# Does throwing a watch into the air cause it to gain or lose time?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity

Suppose I'm on a non rotating planet. I have two identical, perfect watches. I synchronize them. Then I throw one of them into the air and catch it. Does the one I throw into the air gain or lose time with respect to the one I was holding?

Comment: I believe this is precisely answered by the previous question (and answers therein): http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/8314/maximum-time-difference-between-clocks-in-a-gravity-field/ The wording is a little different but otherwise it seems like a duplicate to me.

Comment: @Marek, Someone googling this problem would never find the one you linked as a duplicate. In addition, acceleration and gravitational fields are only theoretically identical. One can imagine gravitational theories where they are different. Consequently the physical situation is not identical.

Comment: So are you talking about something different than general relativity here? If so, please make it explicit in the question. If not, answer is as simple as: proper time is maximized along geodesics. Full stop. I don't find it worthwhile to post this again though...

Comment: No, I don't mean to suggest something other than GR. What I'm pointing out is that "identical answers" is not the same as "duplicate questions". For example, 1+3 and 2+2 have the same answer but they are not duplicate questions.

Comment: @Carl: you have a point there but still, if the answers are essentially the same it means the questions are too, in my opinion. That's because answers usually tend to be a little longer than a single digit. Also, if some question has an answer as short as one sentence (as yours does) I don't think it's a very good question. By the way, from the close button box: "This question covers exactly the same ground as earlier questions on this topic; its answers may be merged with another identical question." I think this is satisfied.

Comment: @Carl: I agree with Marek. This question is not necessary. Especially if you thought of it after reading the other question.

Comment: I agree with @Marek, too. Sorry, @Carl. Moreover, I don't think that an Internet user who doesn't think about these matters physically will find it via Google, anyway. There are many ways (wordings) to formulate the same problem. A female extraterrestrial alien is in love but she's older than her sweetheart, and is offered to be repeatedly shot by a cannon by the Jovian Hegaxon Department of Defense. Will she accept? I write it to Google and it doesn't give me your question (later, it will give, when my comment is added to the index haha).

Comment: Carl, it's not just answers that are equal - after all, there's not any special answer in this question yet so we can't compare. The only difference I see between the questions is that Feynman/Einstein were "blasting" a rocket with clock off while you are "throwing" clock up. Does this change really justify another entry? Is that what you really believe?

Comment: You also write: "In addition, acceleration and gravitational fields are only theoretically identical. One can imagine gravitational theories where they are different. Consequently the physical situation is not identical." - Nope. You are completely wrong. First of all, gravitation appeared in both question: the two questions *are* identical. Moreover, the effect of gravitation and acceleration *is* identical in practice, not just theory. The fact that you don't believe general relativity has nothing to do with it: GR has been proved by science while your-like alternatives have been refuted.

Comment: Your "identical in theory" comment is absolutely isomorphic to someone's comment that the Evening Star and the Morning Star are the same object "only in theory". One needs a "theory" to argue that there is an object called Venus whose position is changing during the day. The person doesn't have to believe that "theories can be trusted". However, as you can see, the person is completely stupid: theories are just necessary tools to learn about the reality. Your situation is unfortunately isomorphic although one talks about "slightly more complicated" questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lawrence has the details, but this question can actually be determined exactly without assuming anything about mass distribution, etc. A geodesic (which is what the watch in free-fall follows) in GR has maximal proper time along it. The "stationary" watch, which is actually accelerated, is following some other path and so must experience a shorter proper time.

Comment: And so the held or "stationary" watch loses time, and the thrown watch gains time.

Comment: Hmmm. But the watch is not in free-fall while it is being thrown and caught. So it seems to me this answer is not sufficient, we would have to give a reason why that is negligible. (We are dealing with very small time differences in the first place.)

Answer (score 2):

What astounds me is there is considerable quibbling over the nature of the question, but nobody answers it!  This is comparatively simple to address.  Let us consider the Schwarzschild metric in a weak gravity field
$$
ds^2~=~-(1~-~2\phi/c^2)dt^2~+~dr^2~+~r^2d\Omega^2
$$
for $\phi~=~GM/r$ the Newtonian gravity potential.  The unit velocity is then
$$
1~=~-(1~-~2\phi/c^2)u_t^2~+~u_r^2~-~\dots
$$
where we can consider the motion in the radial direction for simplicity.  The derivative of this with respect to the proper time $s$ is then
$$
0~=~-(1~-~2\phi/c^2)u_ta_t~+~u_ra_r.
$$
If the gravity potential is zero the solutions are $t~=~g^{-1}\sinh(gs)$ $r~=~g^{-1}\cosh(gs)$, for $g$ the acceleration parameter.  Here $g$ counters the gravitation of the Earth.  If the gravity potential is turned on we can the write the time solution solution as $t~=~g^{-1}\sinh(gs~+~\gamma)$, which we input into the third equation
$$
0~=~-(1~-~2\phi/c^2)g~\cosh(gs)\sinh(gs)~+~g~\cosh(gs~+~\gamma) \sinh(gs~+~\gamma)
$$
$$
=~(1~-~2\phi/c^2)\frac{g}{2}\sinh(2gs~+~2\gamma) ~+~\sinh(2gs)
$$
If we consider weak fields, small accelerations and small proper time $s$ we have
$$
0~\simeq~-(1~-~2\phi/c^2)(g^2s~+~g\gamma)~+~g^2s,
$$
where $\gamma~\simeq~-2\phi gs/c^2$.

The coordinate time is reduced with the turning on of the acceleration.  This implies that the watch on the accelerated frame will mark off a shorter interval of time than the watch which is placed on a geodesic motion in the local gravity field with acceleration $g$.  This is a gravitational version of the twin paradox.  The twin which travels outwards and back is on an accelerated frame, which is a path in spacetime that is non-extremal, or maximal.  As a result the proper time marked off is shorter.

Comment: Schwarzchild metric seems like overkill -- if we are talking about a normal person throwing a normal watch, we could just use an accelerated frame of reference in flat space. Also the comment I made to genneth's answer about throw/catch time applies also -- this is qualitatively different from the twin paradox in that respsect.

Answer (score -1):

I would just point out, there is a twist or two here that would change the result.  For example, if you threw the watch all the way around an airless world and caught it, that thrown watch would record less time than the one you are holding if the angle of launch is less than 60 degrees, more time if the angle is greater than 60 degrees, and exactly the same time if the angle is exactly 60 degrees.

Or, if you cut a tunnel through the planet to the far side, and dropped the watch in, it would fall to the far side, stop, and then fall back to you.  That would record the least amount of time when compared to the standing-still watch.

It is dangerous to use adages like "a geodesic is the path of greatest time between points."  That is not always true.  Plus it is a consequence, not a cause.

It is also not true that the standing watch is being accelerated!  When forces cancel out, the acceleration is zero.  Throw the watch horizontally (at orbital velocity) and both watches have the same gravitational potential energy.  It doesn't matter that one is in free fall and the other is being held up by you.